# Bootstrap 3 won't let hover popover

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, hover, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover

I am using bootstrap 3 and creating a hover popover link.

here is my code

```
$('.toop').popover({html:true,trigger:'hover',placement:'bottom', });
```

html

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone-alt icontip toop" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-original-title="Phone" data-placement="left" data-content="my content and link goes here"></span>
```

what can i do to make it possible to hover to the popover content. Right now, if i hover to the icon, the content will popover, and it will disappear when hover away the icon. I want the popover show up when hover the icon and user can hover to the popover content as well, and only disappear when user hover away from icon and popover content.

Comment: The Bootstrap 2 answer here still works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16740125/twitter-bootstrap-2-3-2-popover-stay-open-while-hovering

Comment: thanks, it worked finally for me. I used the second answer in the link you provided.